# error when inserting in table containing a compsite element in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i'm getting this error when i try to insert into "hotel" table :
ERROR:  cannot cast type record to chambre
LINE 4:                           row(array[(250,'2 place',300),(200...
                                      ^
DETAIL:  Cannot cast type record[] to integer in column 1.

```
create type chambre as(
                   numChambre INTEGER ,
                   typeChambre VARCHAR(30),
                   prix REAL);


create table hotel (
                nom VARCHAR(30),
                Adresse adresse,
                positions positions,
                Chambres chambre[],
                nbPersonnel INTEGER,
                nbEtoile INTEGER,
                telephone VARCHAR(14));         


 insert into hotel values( 'president',
                      row(26,'maraval','oran'),
                      row(27.5,136),
                      row(array[(250,'2 place',300),(200,'1 place',250), 
                      (300,'suite',700)]),
                      60,
                      4,
                      '041-45-86-28');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the details of positions an adresse, but certainly you won't need a `ROW` constructor for any of those.

For `Chambres`, simply cast your constructed array expression to `chambre[]`. It is a good practice to always explicitly specify the column names in an `INSERT` statement to avoid confusion.

```
INSERT INTO hotel 
            ( 
                nom, 
                adresse, 
                positions, 
                chambres, 
                nbpersonnel, 
                nbetoile, 
                telephone 
            ) 
     VALUES 
     ( 
     'president', 
      (26,'maraval','oran'), 
      (27.5,136), 
      array[(250,'2 place',300),(200,'1 place',250),(300,'suite',700)] :: chambre[], 
      60, 
      4, 
     '041-45-86-28' 
      );
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d7d3c93eab0d2838126a27a05f1ad0c9)